# How to identify electrical connectors?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

Can someone help identifying the electrical connectors in this picture? These connectors are from an aftermarket igniter. Also where can one purchase replacement connectors. I have looked [connectors from digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/connectors/index). Any help towards looking for replacement connectors is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Any hardware store (if you're in the USA) will carry these.

Comment: In the motor trade they were (are) called Lucar terminals and available in a range of sizes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as “Spade Connectors”, or “Blade Terminals”. Here are some:
[INSULATED FEMALE PUSH ON TERMINAL 22-18 AWG RED](http://www.electronix.com/insulated-female-push-terminal-awg-red-p-13642.html)

Comment: home despot sells them in their electrical section

Answer (score 1):

These connectors are also called Quick-Disconnect Terminals. Here is a link from Master Carr. [Quick-Disconnect Terminals](https://www.mcmaster.com/#spade-connectors/=1djynbs)

[image: Quick Connects]